# $state.go on search input

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-typeahead

I've built a small movies search app with AngularJS, UI Router, UI Bootstrap Typeahead and Elasticsearch. For reference, I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012048/search-input-and-state-go) yesterday here and received a good, quick answer. I managed to get it working without ng-keypress. I simply put `$state.go()` right in the function and the linking/transition worked. On keypress on the search input it goes from the home/query page to the results page. However, it is NOT displaying any suggestions. Once it goes to the results page... nothing happens. I have to type in the search input again for suggestions and search to execute.

I'm really trying to get functionality where on the hp, as soon as a user types in the search input that it goes to the results page AND once it gets there, that suggestions are displaying and search can be executed.

Here is my code

HTML

```
<form ng-submit="vm.search()" class="form-horizontal col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="hp-search-form"><div class="input-group input-group-lg">
<input type="text" name="q" ng-model="vm.searchTerms" ng-keypress="navigate('search')" placeholder="Search" class="form-control input-lg" uib-typeahead="query for query in vm.getSuggestions($viewValue)" typeahead-show-hint="true" typeahead-focus-first="false" typeahead-on-select="vm.search($item)" auto-focus style="border:0px;">
  <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
  <div ng-show="noResults">
    <i class="fa fa-remove"></i> No Results Found
  </div>
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Search" id="hp-search-button" ng-submit="vm.search()"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i></button>
</span>
```

and the getSuggestions function in the `searchCtrl`

```
    vm.getSuggestions = function(query) {
  $state.go('search');
  console.log(vm.searchTerms);
  vm.isSearching = true;
  console.log(vm.searchTerms);
  return searchService.getSuggestions(query).then(function(es_return){
    console.log(vm.searchTerms);
    var suggestions = es_return.hits.hits;
    if (suggestions) {
      //console.log(suggestions);
      return vm.autocomplete.suggestions = suggestions.map(function(item) {
      return item._source.ymme;
      //console.log(autocomplete.suggestions);
    });
  }
  else {
    vm.autocomplete.suggestions = [];
    vm.noResults = true;
  }
  vm.isSearching = false;
  },
  function(error) {
    //console.log('ERROR: ', error.message);
    vm.isSearching = false;
  });
};
```

Comment: when you have written $state.go('search'); , no further code will execute, try making a plunker

Comment: @MandeepSingh - I'm guessing "when" should be "where" I have written $state.go('search'). I'll try making a plunker, might take some time - never done it before. So no matter where I put $state.go - the code will stop executing...?

Comment: why are u changing state for fetching search results..

Comment: @pritesh because I have a hp/query page and a results page. I want to do it like that because I plan on building the app out over time - just like any other niche/vertical search site.

Comment: try making a Service which will fetch results for you so that you don't need to change the state if not needed

Comment: @MandeepSingh, I've made a service that does that. The search functionality works just fine. I just want to be able to transition between states.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the results along with the $state.go() like so:

```
  $state.go('search', { results: vm.autocomplete.suggestions });
```

You'll be needing to do the $state.go() in the section where you're returning the result ofc. In the config.routes.js file where you have 'search' defined, you'll also need this so the next page can accept the 'results' as part of the $state.params:

```
  params: {
    results: null
  }
```

In the 'search' page, you can then access the search results via this:

```
  $state.params.results
```

Then you can do the work of doing something with the results.